# Ebay style category chooser with mootools, PHP and MySQL?

Tags: php, mysql, mootools

I am looking to create a similar category chooser to ebay, allowing a next level style selector, but built with mootools, php and selecting the categories from MySQL.

Any help or tips on where to look or how to start more than welcome...

Comment: I think you'll get better results when starting out with your 'best try', presenting that & asking whether it fits the bill. For some reason people hate the idea they're doing someone else's work, but have no problem doing the work as soon as they see a possible problem in a current implementation:)

Comment: Thanks Wrikken, this was more of a quick question to find out if there is anything already built, or similar method already in use, rather than me try and build something from scratch

Answer (score 0):

isn't that a simple fly-out menu? you could even do this with pure CSS although i ended up doing something else recently - have a look here http://fragged.org/dev/mooflyout.php (my conceptual staging area) - the flyout is not in production just yet and probably needs more work (built on top of work i found on the web some time ago) but it's good enough as proof of concept that can get you started. just mouseover the items on the menu bar and look at the source, couldn't be simpler. there's an iframe shim to keep the height cross browser but i plan on removing it